# How do I get a key and its value from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, and I want to get a key & value SEPERATED out of it:

```
values = {
    "a": 123,
    "b": 173,
    "c": 152,
    "d": 200,
    "e": 714,
    "f": 71
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
dictValue = values[2] #I know this will be an error
dictKey = "c"
dictValue = 152
```

Thanks!

Comment: use `values.items()`

Comment: By what reasoning should `values[2]` yield a key of c and a value of 152?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. You know `values[2]` is an error, but what is it suppose to represent? Do you basically want some function like `key, value = magic(values, 2)` so that `key == "c"` and `value == 152`, under the assumption that the keys are ordered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an auxiliary dictionary with integer keys:

```
d = dict(enumerate(values.items()))
dictKey, dictValue = d[2]
#('c', 152)
```

Comment: `dict(enumerate(values.items()))` would be much simpler and more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Build a new `dict`:

```py
values = {
    "a": 123,
    "b": 173,
    "c": 152,
    "d": 200,
    "e": 714,
    "f": 71
}

def get_the_idx_to_value_thingy(some_map):
    return {i: v for i, v in enumerate(some_map.values())}
    # or, if you trying to be clever:
    #   return list(some_map.values())

idx_to_value = get_the_idx_to_value_thingy(values)
print(idx_to_value[2])  # > = 152
```

You'll have to call helper function `get_the_idx_to_value_thingy` each time you add/delete a *key* or update an *entry*.

```py
# Oops!
del values['e']; del values['b']
new_idx_map_thingy = get_the_idx_to_value_thingy(values)
# LET's do this!
values['fToTheMAX!'] = values.pop('f')
new_idx_map_thingy = get_the_idx_to_value_thingy(values)
```